# Unknown error on attempt to throw 404 page

Tags: cakephp, php, cakephp-1.2

I have a method in my controller that handles generic page requests, meant for my public pages. I want to throw a 404 when I can't match what is in the URL and what I know are the static content pages.

So I do this:

```
$opts = array(
 'name' => 'Some message',
 'code' => 404,
 'message' => 'Your message here',
 'base' => $this->base
);
$this->layout = 'blank';
$this->cakeError('error', array($opts));
```

The problem is I get this error on a 404 request:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: javascript [APP\views\layouts\default.ctp, line 10]

The "$this->layout = 'blank';" is my attempt to redirect to a blank layout file that doens't include any CSS, JS, etc. But it's ignoring this completely and loading the default template, which has JS includes. I'm guessing that the error routines that load 404 pages don't have access to these methods, which is the source of the error.

But I can't figure out how deal with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's a small bug in your code. Your second parameter to cakeError() is already an array. It should be:

```
$this->cakeError('error', $opts);
```

Second, you can set

```
$this->layout = false;
```

if you want a blank layout.